# Gitlab blame functionality not working: 502 error

Tags: git, gitlab

We've installed our own private Gitlab server, and everything seems to be working fine. Except when I try to do a 'blame' on any file, it will time out with the error

```
502

GitLab is not responding.

Please contact your GitLab administrator if this problem persists.
```

It is a pretty big repository (~7Gb) but I don't think that should matter on a per-file basis, though, should it?

Does this ever happen on Github as well? Is there anything specific in the configuration that might be causing this.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/148

Comment: Hmm, we've got 3GB RAM. Is that still not enough? It looks like the recommended is 2GB. Is the blame particularly more taxing on memory than anything else?

Comment: Please provide more info when reporting bugs or else we won't be able to help. 1) What are the relevant log/production.log lines? 2) Can you reproduce on gitlab.com if you upload the repos there? 3) Does it a happen on every repository or just on the big one? If not, give a minimal test repo. | Blame operations have to browse multiple commits, so if the repo has tons of commits blame might be slow. It blame not slow on your `git blame` locally?

Comment: Thank you Ciro. That helped a lot. I did a test with smaller test repos and was able to see the blame functionality working. I then tried with a smaller commit of my own and was able to get a smaller error

    `Too many changes. 
    To preserve performance only 100 of 131 files displayed.`

It looks like the problem was that the person's changes I was trying to view was using

    `git add .`
instead of

    `git add -u`. Sorry I'm not able to provide a specific error code, but I think that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the GitLab Web UI is no longer the only possibility to trigger a blame.

There is now (August 2019, GitLab 12.2) a [GitLab blame API](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/08/22/gitlab-12-2-released/#git-blame-api) (from [Oleg Zubchenko](https://gitlab.com/RGBD))

> In GitLab 12.2, the new Blame API allows this information to be retrieved directly from GitLab, without needing to checkout the repository.
> This is helpful for scripting and automation, based on the people who’ve recently changed the file.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-blame-from-repository) and [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/51345).

I suspect this will have the same limits you have seen with your large repository, though.

---

You can see "`git blame`" with [GitLab 14.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/01/22/gitlab-14-7-released/#go-to-git-blame-from-code-search-results) (January 2022), but only for code search results, in the non-free tiers:

> ### Go to Git blame from code search results
>
> Users often want to understand more about code search results, such as when was a file changed or by whom.
>
> With GitLab 14.7, users can easily answer these questions with fewer clicks by using the **View blame** link in Global Search results.
> This change adds another link next to lines of code when hovering over results from a code search.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_7/go_directly_to_git_blame_from_global_search.png -- Go to Git blame from code search results]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/#code-search) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/327052).

---

[GitLab 16.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/01/18/gitlab-16-8-released/#view-blame-information-directly-in-the-file-page) (January 2024) adds:

> ### View blame information directly in the file page
>
> In previous versions of GitLab, viewing file blame required you to access a different page. Now you can view the file blame information directly from the file page.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_8/blame-in-file-page.png -- View blame information directly in the file page]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/git_blame.html#view-blame-for-a-file) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/11471).